# Joomla 3.0 SEF URLs sending to random wrong articles

Tags: plugins, joomla-extensions, joomla-sef-urls, joomla3.0

My site [eighttwentydesign](http://www.eighttwentydesign.com) is running Joomla 3.0. I have SEF URLs on, and have done for sometime without issue. But today when you go to the site, and click on anything, say portfolio you get the home page under the portfolio's URL, but if you add a leading slash at the end, the right article (portfolio) shows. Additionally, if you click on say "Web Design" it sends you to the Portfolio page. I might add this menu is a menu within Joomla - not be adding internal links manually

Doesn't work: http://www.eighttwentydesign.com/portfolio

Does work: http://www.eighttwentydesign.com/portfolio/

I have checked the .htaccess, and actually reverted it to the original with no luck, I have check Global Config but I can't see anything which may cause this. It was working nicely yesterday. I haven't adapted with any PHP source or anything in the past few weeks, the only notifiable thing I have done is yesterday enabling the Cache - have others experienced problems after doing this? I have disabled it under global config, with no avail.

Exact Joomla Version is 3.0.2 with very few plugins

I do have daily backups, but would rather a solution and be able to figure out a prevention from that, rather than just putting on a band aid.

I've search for a good couple of hours, and aside from just not being able to fix it, it appears no one else is experiencing this, so I am starting to think it may be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I was about to post this I discovered my solution.

If you are having your SEF URLs display the wrong content then solve it by disabling the Cache plugin. You can do this by doing the following steps

1. Login to Joomla backend
2. Navigate to Extensions > Plugins
3. Go to "System Cache"
4. Disable system cache

I hope this helps someone in the future as I really struggled to find any answers on this.